# Navigate through images using next and previous button HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have an image gallery with a bunch of photos. I have a next and previous buttons next to the image to navigate through the images (Only single image of the gallery is displayed on the page at a time). 
On click of this 'next' and 'previous' buttons, the user should be able to navigate to next/ previous image respectively. I am not sure how this could be achieved.
I am new to web development and I am looking for a resource which would help me with the same. Any resource which could guide me through this would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to do this as exercise or do you mind using completed plugins? This is only one of many solutions: http://galleria.aino.se/ -- For own development you should start with a predefined list of images and look for jQuery's method to replace html and for example binding click events.

Comment: A simple but good plugin would not be a bad option either. SInce I am a beginner it would help me understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the Jquery library. (Jquery.com) or even some type of plugins. worst case scenario you can dynamically generate divs with unique IDS and then hide and show them based on the id with the buttons.